# How to write a lot of data efficiently to a large text file using windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with every pixel of an image and its respective color. I want to extract every pixel coordinate with a specific color and put the coordinate rapidly in a text file. The code I use gets very slow after a while. I need to extract around 80,000 of the 220,000 pixel coordinates. I am looking for a efficient way to extract a lot of data from a text file, process it and put it in a text file.

### The layout of the text file:

"pixel coordinate (x,y)" "rgb as 16bit values" "hex color code" "color name"

example:

```
105,44: (0,32896,0)  #008000  green
106,44: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
107,44: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFF  white
108,44: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000FF  black
```

### this is the code I use:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (temp.txt) do (
for /F "tokens=4,*" %%B in ("%%A") do (
::store coordinates of green pixels
if /i %%B==green (
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%C in ("%%A") do (

set Coordinate=%%C
set Coordinate=!Coordinate:~0,-1!
set Coordinate=!Coordinate:,= !
echo !Coordinate!>>greenPixels.txt
))))
```

if I don't append the coordinates into a text file the code runs relatively fast. So I am looking for a way to rapidly append a variable into a text file. I tried to put all the coordinates into a variable and put this variable into a text file at the end. This got also very slow after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the destination file for each and every line, then close it again to open it again for the next line is very ineffective. Write the whole data in one go instead. Also, filter your data as early as possible so you have less data to process.

Use just a single `for` loop and avoid `set` variable managing.

```
@echo off
setlocal
(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=,:" %%A in ('type temp.txt ^|find "green"') do (
   echo %%A %%B
))>greenPixels.txt
```

If you need to create files for every color (I have a feeling that's what you want):

```
@echo off
setlocal
(for /f "tokens=1,4 delims=: " %%A in (temp.txt) do (
   for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%K in ("%%A") do (
      if "%%B" == "green" 1>&3 echo %%K %%L
      if "%%B" == "red"   1>&4 echo %%K %%L
      if "%%B" == "black" 1>&5 echo %%K %%L
      if "%%B" == "white" 1>&6 echo %%K %%L
   )  
)) 3>greenpixels.txt 4>redpixels.txt 5>blackpixels.txt 6>whitepixels.txt
```

This splits the colors into separate output streams inside the loop. Outside the loop these different streams are redirected to their corresponding files.

You can use stream 1 to 9, so you could split up to nine colors (for Stream 1 just skip the `1>&x` part) so we are able to keep the efficient "write only once" method. I intentionally left out Stream 1 and 2, because they are reserved for STDOUT and STDERR, but nevertheless, they can be used the same way.

(about half a minute for ~238.000 lines of `temp.txt`)